# Group homology computation

Tags: finite-groups, homology-cohomology

If I know the homology (groups) of two abelian groups and I want to find the homology of their direct sum, how can I proceed?
Is it pssible to take the direct sum of the two resolutions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about doing something like computing that $Ext_{\mathbb{Z}}(G \oplus H, K) = Ext_{\mathbb{Z}}(G, K) \oplus Ext_{\mathbb{Z}}(H,K)$.

The direct sum of two free abelian groups is free abelian (likewise for projective, likewise for injective), and direct sum commutes with taking homology. So, yes, it does suffice to take the direct sums of their resolutions.

Comment: It should be a TOR, if it is homology, right?W?ithot dealing with 'properties or theories of homology, I wondered how to explicitly use the known resolutions...

Answer (score 0):

I was reading Evens book, and I found that you may use Kunneth formula. That' s what I will check now for more generality.

Comment: Are you talking about the cohomology of the group $G \times G'$? Because in that case, the Kunneth formula will apply (since $B ( G \times G') = BG \times BG'$). It's kind of unclear what you are asking about, to me anyway. Maybe you can add more to your question.

Comment: Exactly!!Or homology, using free resolutions.